How to use 'git show' to retrieve a single file but specify the remote repo url for Azure DevOps?
This:
git show ci:path1/path2/file.txt

works perfectly, as advertized (git show branch-name:path/to/your/file.txt).
The documentation also says that you can do this to retrieve the file from another repo:
git show <repository-url>/<branch-name>:path/to/your/file.txt

But I cannot find the way to specify the url for Azure Devops repo.
I tried:
git show https://myOrg@dev.azure.com/myOrg/myProject/_git/myRepo/ci:path1/path2/file.txt

... and I get:

fatal: invalid object name 'https'

If I don't put 'https' I get:

fatal: invalid object name '//myOrg@dev.azure.com/myOrg/myProject/_git/myRepo/ci'.

If I use:
git show //dev.azure.com/myOrg/myProject/_git/myRepo/ci:path1/path2/file.txt

I get:

fatal: invalid object name '//dev.azure.com/myOrg/myProject/_git/myRepo/ci'.

(which looks promising, but is not quite there yet).

Do you already have that URL as a remote?

Yes:
git remote -v
origin  https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/myProject/_git/myRepo (fetch)
origin  https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/myProject/_git/myRepo (push)

You can use origin in place of the full URL, then - but be sure to git fetch first (git show won't connect to the remote).

Not sure I understand - I need to get the file from another repo. Not the repo the current branch is based on.

@frank-monroe why do you need the file from another repository? Are you running a pipeline that will download and use the file or...?


The documentation also says that you can do this to retrieve the file from another repo: git show <repository-url>/<branch-name>:path/to/your/file.txt

The format is not supported in devops repo. The git show command does not accept a remote repository URL as an argument. Please check the official doc git show for the details.
As a workaround, you can use rest api Items - Get to get the content of the target file.
Command below:
curl -s -u :{PAT} "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo}/items?path={filepath}&versionDescriptor.version={branch}&api-version=7.1-preview.1"

path: the file path in the repo
versionDescriptor.versionOptions: the target branch
My target file:

Command result, it outputs the file content:


For those who prefer POSH:
`
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":{PAT}"))
$url="https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/myProject/_apis/git/repositories/myRepo/items?path=path/to/file.txt&versionDescriptor.version=ci&api-version=7.1-preview.1"


$file = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get

